# Entire Table Search Form - Microsoft Access 2010

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to create a search form that can search from one table at a time based on the table selected by the user from a combo-box.  I have a text box called searchCriteria and the combo-box is called TableList.  The idea is that if the user wanted to search customer_table, she would select “customer_table” in the combo box, enter her search criteria in the text box, and press the search button.  If she wanted to search order_table, she would select that table from the combo-box and so on.  I would like the query to return all full records pertaining to the criteria entered.  So, for example, if the user searched “James” from the customer table, I would like the full records (all fields) returned where the criteria “James” is present:

```
 
    Company               |   First Name    |   Last Name   |   Account #   |   Sales Rep
    Jammy Juice           |   James         |   Dan         |   555         |   Jim Halbert
    Jameson Car Shop      |   Tom           |   Cramb       |   556         |   Dwight Smiles
    Landon Refrigeration  |   Bob           |   McVance     |   557         |   James Bland
```

From my understanding, this will require some VBA to write a query…

I am assuming the query would be something like the following:
SELECT t.* FROM customer_table t WHERE (t.*)::text LIKE '%James%';

Where the string entered (James) and the table name (customer_table) are entered by the user.

Simply, I'm having trouble getting the form data (the table name and search text) into my query.

Does anyone know how to implement this in Microsoft Access 2010?  Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The *any sequence of characters* wildcard in Access is ***** not **%**. If you want to search all fields in Access then you could concatenate all the fields:

```
WHERE [FirstName] & [Surname] & [City] & [Address] 
LIKE "'*" & Forms!frmSearch!txtFind & "*'"
```

You might separate the fields with  a distinct character, to prevent finding words that overlap between the fields.

Or, individually, but less efficient:

```
WHERE [FirstName] Like "'*" & Forms!frmSearch!txtFind & "*'" 
OR [Surname] Like "'*" & Forms!frmSearch!txtFind & "*'" 
OR [Address] Like "'*" & Forms!frmSearch!txtFind & "*'"
```

(I don't know where `(t.*)::text` came from, but it is not Access.)

So you will firstly need to discover all the field-names for the table they have selected. You can obtain the `TableDef` for the table-name they have selected and loop through its `Fields` collection to obtain the field-names. There are other ways to do this. For example, [GetSchema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kcax58fh.aspx).

Comment: I would pause to consider your approach though. It is going to be very inefficient, and probably unreliable, as you are searching all data-types but treating them all as text. An alternative would be to synchronise comboboxes: Let them select the table-name, then populate a second combobox with its field-names - but just those of data-type text.

Comment: Comment 1:  This is a particularly good answer because the OP is 'having trouble getting the form data (the table name and search text) into my query' and the necessary approach is demonstrated here.

Comment: Comment 2: I think the OP may be particularly interested in the bit at the end about `TableDef`.  That has worked well for me in this situation, and `Field` attributes even let you choose fields by data type (text VS numeric, etc).  Recommend OP runs a search on that as many tutorials are available.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the *LAZY* way of doing this in Access 2010:

1. Create a continuous form
2. In the form Properties, set `Navigation Buttons` = Yes
3. When you open the form, you will see a `Search` box:

[image: Search box in Navigation Bar]

4. Type what you want to search for. Hit `Enter` to see further matches.

Notes:

- This searches **all** fields displayed on the form
- This does not restrict records to the search term
- This is probably not a good idea for very large recordsets
- There might be a need to do some user training for this feature

Answer (score -2):

To refer text selected in combo-box

```
Me.TableList.Column(0)
```

To refer text in text box

```
Me.searchCriteria.Text
```

So your VBA command will look like

```
DoCmd.RunSQL("SELECT t.* FROM " & Me.TableList.Column(0) & " t WHERE (t.*)::text LIKE '%" & Me.searchCriteria.Text & "%'")
```

Comment: The wildcard character in Access is '*', not '%'. We cannot refer to the `Text` property, just remove the `.Text`. But `(t.*)::text` doesn't work in Access - I don't know where this is from, but it is not Access.

Comment: I have provided the codes to refer the form data in the query assuming the query works independently in Access.